# next_permutation not by reference?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I do not understand why inside the loop, the position of the values are changed. But outside `do, while loop`, all the values return to the original positions. Thus i need the `//here` code. I also tried a pointer array, but it showed the same behavior. Why so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2};
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            cout << a[i];
        cout << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(a, a + 3));
    cout << endl;
    // here
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 0;

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            cout << a[i];
        cout << endl;
    } while (prev_permutation(a, a + 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you read documentation of [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)?

Comment: `{0, 1, 2}` is lexicographically lowest, so if you continue looping based on `std::next_permutation` result, you will always end with this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how `next_permutation` is defined. The last permutation (the one that returns false) is the one that puts the elements in sorted order.

I suppose there is another misunderstanding. Here:

```
do
{
    print_permutation();
} while (next_permutation(a, a + 3));
```

The last permutation you print inside the loop is that one before the one that makes `next_permutation` return `false`. Hence in the last iteration you are not printing the same permutation as outside of the loop. It is similar to:

```
bool increment(int& i) {
    ++i;
    return i<10;
}

int i = 0;
do {
   std::cout << i;
} while( increment(i) );

std::cout << i;
```

The last value printed inside the loop is `9`, but the value of `i` after the loop is `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time it is called, `std::next_permutation` generates an permutation `P'` of the given container `a` where the current permutation is, say, `P`. As long as the permutation `P'` it generates is *greater* than `P`, it returns `true`. However, in the case for `P` being the *greatest* (i.e., see below for an explanation of *greatness*) permutation of the elements in the given container `a`, for instance `P=[2, 1, 0]` the next permutation `P'` it generates is `[0, 1, 2]`, which is not greater than `P`. In that case, it returns `false` and the loop terminates. But, due to the side effect of the process, once the function returns, the elements in the container are already placed in that smallest permutation possible. That is why you see those elements in their *smallest* permutation possible after the loop terminates.

The word *greater* may be a little confusing. Basically `std::next_permutation` uses whatever comparison operators are available to compare individual elements and ends up iterating over them in a way that lexicographically increases with each following permutation. So, for a vector of `[0, 1, 2]`, it would iterate the following permutations in that order:

```
0, 1, 2
0, 2, 1
1, 0, 2
1, 2, 0
2, 0, 1
2, 1, 0
```

That is why, the function recognizes that `[0,1,2]` would **not** be a *greater* permutation after `[2,1,0]` and returns false.